# Which will be given preferences while calling method with parameter as (int, int), Method with signature (int, int) or (Integer, Integer)

Tags: java

I have method calling with passing parameters as (4,5).

I have two methods with parameters :

```
method1(int a, int b);
method1(Integer a, Integer b);
```

which method will be called and why?

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: Answering "try it out" is not productive. It may give the OP the answer to "which?", provided that their particular compiler behaves correctly, but not the answer to "why?". For the latter, and preferably for the former too, you should look in the Java Language Specification which is available on Oracle's website.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException not trying it out in the first place is not productive either, and a violation of SO policy. that way, the OP could have created a better founded question: "I noticed that when passing two ints to an overloaded method (int, int) and (Integer, Integer), variant x is called. How come this method, and not the overloaded one?" This shows at least some initiative. As for the why part: a lot of times people check the title for the question, which states the entire question, except for the why part, giving the impression that with trying it out, the OP has the answer

Comment: Of course, the best solution is not to have both of those methods.  Do they do different things?  If they do the same thing, you can get rid of the second one and any code which passes Integer objects will automatically unbox them in order to match the first method.

Answer (score 5):

This has been specified in [The Java® Language Specification, §15.12.2. Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2):

> …
>
> The remainder of the process is split into three phases, to ensure compatibility with versions of the Java programming language prior to Java SE 5.0. The phases are:
>
> 1. The first phase ([§15.12.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2)) performs overload resolution without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.
>    …
> 2. The second phase ([§15.12.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.3)) performs overload resolution while allowing boxing and unboxing, but still precludes the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the third phase.
>    …
> 3. The third phase ([§15.12.2.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.4)) allows overloading to be combined with variable arity methods, boxing, and unboxing.

Therefore, since `method1(int a, int b)` is found in the first phase, it will be used. `method1(Integer a, Integer b)` would only be found in the second phase, if no matching method has been found in the first phase.

Answer (score 1):

`4` and `5` are `int` literals. Therefore they match your `method1(int a, int b)` without any conversion. Therefore `method1(int a, int b)` will be chosen.

In order to choose `method1(Integer a, Integer b)`, the compiler would have to box the two `int` literals to `Integer`s. That can only take place if no method matching your method name and the passed parameters which doesn't require boxing/unboxing conversions is found. Clearly, that's not the case here, since `method1(int a, int b)` exists. Even a `method1(long a, int b)` or `method1(long a, long b)` or `method1(int a, long b)` would be preferred over `method1(Integer a, Integer b)`, since they don't require boxing conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Both @Eran and @Holger answers are correct and very well explained, but if you want to try your code by yourself, here it is:

```
public class Answer {

    static void method1(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("Inside the method1(int, int)");
    }

    static void method1(Integer a, Integer b) {
        System.out.println("Inside the method1(Integer, Integer)");
    }

    //Test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method1(4, 5);
        method1(Integer.valueOf(4), Integer.valueOf(5));

    //  method1(4, Integer.valueOf(5)); //Ambiguous method call - won't compile

    }
}
```

The output is:

`Inside the method1(int, int)
Inside the method1(Integer, Integer)`